# Failed to import TensorFlow on Ubuntu system

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow

```
mohanakrishnavh@mohanakrishnavh-Inspiron-7559:~$ python
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohanakrishnavh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/mohanakrishnavh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/mohanakrishnavh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/mohanakrishnavh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/mohanakrishnavh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcudnn.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mohanakrishnavh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/mohanakrishnavh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/mohanakrishnavh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohanakrishnavh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/mohanakrishnavh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/mohanakrishnavh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/mohanakrishnavh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/mohanakrishnavh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcudnn.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
```

Comment: Apparently you are trying to install the GPU enabled version of tensorflow, the error you get is an indication the CUDA is not available (this comes from the packages libcudnn5 [download after registration](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) ). It makes sense to follow the installation instructions from this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#nvidia_requirements_to_run_tensorflow_with_gpu_support)

Comment: Yes, cudnn is not installed correctly in your system. If you don't want to run with GPU try installing the cpu-only version of tensorflow.